# Installing QGIS plugin from command line or Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, installation

I am looking for a way to install and activate plugins in QGIS without accessing the GUI. I have a QGIS instance running on a remote server where I run standalone Python scripts that process the data.

I would like to install a couple of plugins so that I can run their algorithms using `processing.run()`. Either a command line or from Python script solution would work for me.

I had no luck searching through the documentation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO best way to install QGIS plugin is **qgis-plugin-manager**. This is usage example:

```
pip3 install qgis-plugin-manager
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
cd ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
qgis-plugin-manager init
qgis-plugin-manager update
qgis-plugin-manager install "your_plugin_name"
```

And then maybe you need to activate plugin. To do this, you should find in file `~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini` line `[PythonPlugins]` and enable your plugin below, for example:

```
[PythonPlugins]
your_plugin_name=true
```

If you don't know exact your plugin name, you can find it after installation on a line starting with:

```
plugin_installer\seen_plugins=
```

Comment: You need to fix `qgis-plugin-master` by `qgis-plugin-manager`. The link to the documentation of QGIS-Plugin-Manager : https://github.com/3liz/qgis-plugin-manager

Comment: I just edited your answer. Note for QGIS Server, plugins doesn't need to be activated in your `ini` file. Link to the documentation about installing plugins on a server https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/plugins.html#with-a-command-line-tool

Answer (score 3):

For testing an approach, I arbitrarily chose "Append Features to Layer" and, with its link from plugins repository of QGIS:

```
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AppendFeaturesToLayer/version/1.0.0/download/
```

by using following **ariac** command (aria package was previously installed in my GNU/Linux Debian):

```
aria2c -d /home/zeito/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AppendFeaturesToLayer/version/1.0.0/download/
```

it was successfully downloaded in plugin folder:

```
~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
```

of my QGIS 3.12.1 as **AppendFeaturesToLayer-1.0.0.zip**. With command lines, I can unpack this zip file and run make, in plugin folder, for activating it before launching QGIS. So, I think it is possible to create a bash script for all process (downloading, unpacking and activating) for whatever plugin.

**Editing Note:**

With Python it was also possible. It's just a matter of making interactive following script.

```
from os import system

qgis_plugin_path = "/home/zeito/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins"
qgis_plugin_repository = "https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AppendFeaturesToLayer/version/1.0.0/download/"

cmd = "aria2c -d " + qgis_plugin_path + " " + qgis_plugin_repository

system(cmd)
```

Comment: While this approach is something that works, you need to know a lot besides the name of the plugin (i.e. current version) to get the correct link to download the file. I was wondering if there is a way to do something like `QgsApplication.installPlugin("plugin_name)`.

Comment: Only methods in **QgsApplication** with prefix 'install' are 'installEventFilter', 'installNativeEventFilter' and 'installTranslator'. You can search each one function.