# How to enable QGIS plugins from command line?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, command-line

I was able write a test plugin and install it to QGIS (ver 3.24, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). The plugin shows up in the dialogbox from the `Plugins -> Manage and Install plugins...` menu. It is shown under the `Installed` category but not activated (i.e. not checked) by default. So, it's not visible on the toolbar by default.

Is there a way to activate a plugin by default (so that it shows up in the main UI)?

Related question:

[Installing QGIS plugin from command line or Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356517)

There is a deleted answer/non-answer asking this:

> How do you exactly activate the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate plugin find in file ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini line [PythonPlugins] and enable your plugin below, for example:

```
[PythonPlugins]
your_plugin_name=true
```

If you don't know exact your plugin name, you can find it after installation on a line starting with:

```
plugin_installer\seen_plugins=
```